# Where does ModSecurity store the list of blocked IP address?

Tags: mod-security

SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "@streq 403" \
  "phase:5, \
  pass, \
  id:4001, \
  setvar:ip.block_script=+1, \
  expirevar:ip.block_script=1800, \
  msg:'Attack Detected'"

SecRule ip:block_script "@ge 10" \
  "phase:1, \
  deny, \
  status:406, \
  id:4002, \
  msg:'Repetitive Attack from the same IP Address'"

The function of the rule above is to block an IP Adress after 10 consecutive attacks. What is the name of the file which store the list of blocked IP addresses?

Answer (score 1):

It stores them SecDataDir as set in your modsecurity.conf file.

There will be an ip.dir and ip.pag file. It stores them in dbm format.

To be honest using a shared file for a high volume transactional process like a web server isn't great and you [often see errors when multiple processes try to access it at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744536/how-to-disable-modsecurity-collection-store-write-to-dbm-file).

Using a web server, to protect itself isn't that great, as it can take as much processing power to deflect it, as to process it. However it can be useful to protect more delicate backend app servers which maybe can't handle the volume that a web server can.

Comment: There is nothing in the directory

Comment: Does Apache user have write permission to it? Have your rules ever fired?

Comment: Correction: It is stored in the SDBM format (before v3). As of mod_Security 3.0, they moved to something called 'LMDBM' which may have some advantages, but uses a B+ tree format, resulting in theoretically longer access times.